# WLST query (List deployed applications and hosts together)

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g, wlst

I have two WLST queries. I execute it through WebLogic Scripting Tool console. These  queries are:

1) List of deployed applications and status:

```
connect('weblogic','password','t3://localhost:7001')
cd('AppDeployments')
deplymentsList=cmo.getAppDeployments()
for app in deplymentsList:
      domainConfig()
      cd ('/AppDeployments/'+app.getName()+'/Targets')
      mytargets = ls(returnMap='true')
      domainRuntime()
      cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
      cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
      for targetinst in mytargets:
            curstate4=cmo.getCurrentState(app.getName(),targetinst)
            print app.getApplicationName(), targetinst, curstate4;
```

Output example:

- WeblogicApp     Cluster1    STATE_ACTIVE
- DMS Application AdminServer STATE_ACTIVE
- Benefits        Cluster2    STATE_ACTIVE

2) List of hosts-machines

```
connect('weblogic','password','t3://localhost:7001')     
svrs = cmo.getServers()
domainRuntime()
for host in svrs: 
    machine = host.getMachine();
    print "Host:  " + machine.getName()
```

Output example:

- Host: 192.168.200.1
- Host: 192.168.200.2
- Host: 192.168.200.3
- Host: Machine-0
- Host: Machine-1
- Host: Machine-2

I need to get both info (an application and their host or shared hosts if they have it more than one). I don't know how to solve and mix the queries to get both info in one query, or at least to get the info related about deployment application - hosts in the second query.

The output needed is something like that:

- WeblogicApp     Cluster1 STATE_ACTIVE 192.168.200.2
- WeblogicApp     Cluster1 STATE_ACTIVE 192.168.200.3
- DMS Application AdminServer STATE_ACTIVE 192.168.200.1
- DMS Application AdminServer STATE_ACTIVE Machine-1
- DMS Application AdminServer STATE_ACTIVE Machine-2
- Benefits        Cluster1    STATE_ACTIVE Machine-0
- ..............

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late to the party. But if anybody else comes by searching for answers I came up with extension of the first script to give the desired result:

```
connect('weblogic','password','t3://localhost:7001')
setShowLSResult(false)
cd('AppDeployments')
deplymentsList=cmo.getAppDeployments()
domainConfig()
for app in deplymentsList:
    cd ('/AppDeployments/'+app.getName()+'/Targets')
    mytargets = ls(returnMap='true')
    for targetinst in mytargets:
        domainRuntime()
        cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
        cd('AppRuntimeStateRuntime')
        curstate4 = cmo.getCurrentState(app.getName(),targetinst)
        domainConfig()
        cd('/AppDeployments/'+app.getName()+'/Targets/'+targetinst)
        myType = cmo.getType()
        if myType == 'Cluster':
            myServers = cd('/AppDeployments/'+app.getName()+'/Targets/'+targetinst+'/Servers', returnMap='true')
            for server in myServers:
                cd('/AppDeployments/'+app.getName()+'/Targets/'+targetinst+'/Servers/'+server)
                machineName = cmo.getMachine().getName()
                print app.getApplicationName(), targetinst, curstate4, machineName
        elif myType == 'Server':
            cd('/AppDeployments/'+app.getName()+'/Targets/'+targetinst)
            machineName = cmo.getMachine().getName()
            print app.getApplicationName(), targetinst, curstate4, machineName
```

The output will be similar to the output stated in the original question.